# Unable to open admin panel after SSL activation

Tags: magento-1.9, php, aws

Server : Amazon with CDN
Admin link : https://www.gleitsichtbrille.de/index.php/ag_supervista/

If I do the setting `'Use Secure URLs in Admin' => 'No'`, it is working fine and if I change to `'Yes'` then it is showing an error of 'too many redirections please remove cache'. 
I have already removed cache and session folder, still facing the same issue.

The site is live, so currently setting is `'Use Secure URLs in Admin' => 'No'`.

Comment: it is working my side.

Comment: Its working cause I have done  setting is 'Use Secure URLs in Admin' => 'No'. If I do the setting to secure URL for admin panel. It will show error.

Comment: please check my ans.

Comment: Is there any setting in.htaccess file?

Comment: Admin panel login page is getting open with below code:
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'])) {
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
        $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
        $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

1. Go into the database and in the table `core_config_data` update the record with the “path” of `web/secure/use_in_admindata` by setting the `value` field to `0`.
2. Repeat this process using the record with the “path” of `web/secure/use_in_frontend` and again set the `value` field to 0.
3. Using SSH, log into my hosting account, and issue a `rm -rf ~/public_html/magento/var/cache` command.

if you are on the shared host then just rename the cache directory  , it will be created automatically . Enjoy

Comment: I have already mentioned that I have followed all above steps.